# Sort Date in Mysql table in DESC order

Tags: mysql

I want to show date column in DESC order where date is entered as VARCHAR and is in order 20-JUN-2007 I have already used ORDER BY RIGHT(vPublishedDate, 4) but it doesn't effect the month and date

Comment: Thanks to @mathematical.coffee now i want to get MAX value from same field .PLZ help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using [`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) (take into account the other answers about converting the column to date, although you may not have control over the database):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(vPublishedDate,'%d-%M-%Y')
```

As an example:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('20-JUN-2007','%d-%M-%Y') as Date;
+------------+
| Date       |
+------------+
| 2007-06-20 |
+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution :) can you help me a littele bit more ? I want to get MAX value from same field i.e vPublishedDate ,plz

Comment: I think you'll be able to work that out for yourself, given that you now know how to convert `vPublishedDate` into a date within a query.

Comment: ok got it SELECT * FROM articles WHERE STR_TO_DATE(vPublishedDate,'%d-%M-%Y') = (SELECT MAX(STR_TO_DATE(vPublishedDate,'%d-%M-%Y')) FROM articles)

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using a `VARCHAR` to store a `DATE`? Use a `DATE` to store a `DATE` and then, as if by magic, sorting works all on its own.

Answer (score 1):

You *really* should be storing dates as dates, not character-type fields. Then you wouldn't need to worry about this sort of "SQL gymnastics" (as I like to call it).

Databases are for storing data, *not* formatting.

By forcing yourself to manipulate sub-columns, you basically prevent the database from performing any useful optimisations.

In order to do what you want with the data you have you have to do something like:

- use substring to extract individual sub-column information to get them in the order you want; and
- use some sort of lookup to turn a string like "NOV" into 11 (since the month names will sort as DEC, FEB, AUG, APR, JAN, JUL, JUN, MAR, MAY, NOV, OCT, SEP).

And this would be a serious performance killer. Now there *may* be a function which can turn that particular date format into a proper date but I urge you: don't use it.

Set up or change your database to use an intelligent schema and all these problems will magically disappear.

It's a lot easier to turn a date column into any sort of output format than to do the same with a character column.

Answer (score 0):

Change that `VARCHAR`to a `Date` type column, if you can.

You can also try this, although this is **NOT** the **RIGHT** approach.

Select STR_TO_DATE(your_date_column,'%d/%m/%Y') AS your_new_date from your_table order by your_new_date DESC

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the varchar to date using [str_to_date](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) and then you can apply the sorting logic.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the type as Date.
Then run a script which converts your dates to the correct DB format.

Sorting would be then be just as simple as sorting ids in MySql